# Is there any function for Tampermonkey to accept HTML/CSS scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been Finding this out for months. How can we let HTML codes get accepted on Tampermonkey? 
My code here is

```html
 '<i class="material-icons" style="margin-right:1px;font-size:32px;color:#40C4FF;vertical-align:middle;margin-top:-6px;">check_circle</i>';
```

and I want to put this script on Tampermonkey, But it dosn't accept it. How do i figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

@Matchtoolz

Please try this code,To Is there any function for Tampermonkey to accept HTML/CSS scripts?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Open CodeProject Links
// @namespace  http://hibbard.eu/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Opens links from the CodeProject newsletter
// @match      http://www.codeproject.com/script/Mailouts/*
// @copyright  2012+, hibbard.eu
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(document).ready(function() {
  var hrefs = new Array();
  var elements = $('.headline > a');
  elements.each(function() {
    hrefs.push($(this).attr('href'))
  });

  $('body').append('<input type="button" value="Open Links" id="CP">')
  $("#CP").css("position", "fixed").css("top", 0).css("left", 0);
  $('#CP').click(function(){
    $.each(hrefs, function(index, value) {
      setTimeout(function(){
       window.open(value, '_blank');
      },1000);
    });
  });
});
```

I hope this information will be usefull for you.

Thank you.